# Sending a request to local URL/IP from the clients browser through a script on the webserver

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, ip, local

I have a device running local in my network that can be controlled and receive commands by a HTTP request. E.g. a GET request like that would do an action: http://192.168.2.99/?do=something

I want to build a web software that interacts with this device on the clients side. Now I am searching for a way to trigger this by php/html/js.

Tried this idea so far but the browsers are blocking this because of security reasons. Do you have any idea how to solve it or find a way?

Thanks

```
<iframe name="iframe" src=""></iframe>

<a id="framelink" href="http://192.168.2.99/?do=something" target="iframe">Link</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('framelink').click();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi shadowdoser, please share the error screenshot along with description i.e. browser error.

Comment: Running "http://192.168.2.99/?do=something" manually local in the browser gets a json response and does some action. But with the code I posted the iframe stays blank/white. Tested on firefox and chrome.

Comment: why need `iframe` inside the site ? a regular page it's just fine for the purpose. On other site it wanted to link `your site`, then add `iframe` with `src` pointed to `your site`,

Comment: when you call urls via AJAX that are not on the domain as the website you have to use JSONP - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp OR you use a backend server on your website which calls the device urls.